# I want to triple boot Windows 7, XP and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows

So. I have windows 7 and Ubuntu right now. And i want to add windows XP too. I did some research and found out that you need to install everything in order from XP to Ubuntu. But i have windows 7 and Ubuntu already. And i want to ask is there a way without re-installing Windows 7 and Ubuntu.
P.S.: Thanks to anyone who will reply.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should have installed both Windows first, then install Ubuntu, but you can install XP now, find a way to reinstall grub, then you can triple-boot with XP,7 and Ubuntu. There are many guides on how to reinstall grub, some are complicated and some are not complicated.

Comment: (Sorry if i dont know something i am new to OS installation) So what i understand i need to make partition, install XP on it and then install grub?

Comment: yes. that will work.